# Best Strategy to remove the unused or duplicate indexes

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

I have searched the Internet a lot about this but I'm still not comfortable making a decision.

One of our reporting databases is 350 GB (it acts as a subscriber for transaction replication where indexes are not moved during replication), the index file group was created almost 4 years ago residing on its own drive.

This drive is now almost full with index files occupying 200 GB created for various tables involved on subscribed database.

My main goal is to start cleaning the 3 most used tables. Below are the details:

1. Table 1: 88 GB with 98659075 rows. Number of nonclustered indexes=88
2. Table 2 : 52 GB with 17793712 rows. Number of nonclustered indexes=52
3. table 3: 48 GB with 8666642 rows. Number of nonclustered indexes=44

The number of indexes definitely seems large, but since this is a reporting db server does that sound reasonable? Is there a specific number of indexes on the same table which raises a red flag for performance (just want to know what you guys think)?

Secondly, I have gathered a months data from the dmvs `dm_db_index_usage_stats`,`dm_db_missing_index_columns`, `dm_db_missing_index_group_stats`,`dm_db_missing_index_groups` to decide which indexes I can safety remove. So, just want to know what should be my strategy here based on above gathered data to delete the indexes for better performance and to save the disk space as well?

Comment: We can't really answer this question. Is a month's worth of usage enough for *you* to make a decision? What if you have reports that are run at end of quarter, end of year, at tax time, seasonally, only after exceptional events, etc.?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Agree with you on a decision to make. Although i had this confirmed from reporting team and report owners as well that 99.9 % of the reports which covers all the important ones are either run daily weekly or monthly, hardly there is any which runs in quarter or yearly. The data i have gathered is from Jan1st 2016. Any starting point, because i had to remove now since disk space is all used here.

Comment: Ok, then it seems obvious, delete the ones that have only write operations and no reads, and then after that, again, I don't know how we can help with strategy - is an index that has a read:write ratio of 20% worth keeping? 25%? 50%? 75%? We have no idea where your trade-off will lie. In general, you want to favor keeping the indexes that have lots of read activity. In specific, you're on your own.

Comment: Of course **an exact duplicate** index can always be deleted with prejudice.

Comment: @Erik Yes, true, I was giving the benefit of the doubt that those weren't the ones up for debate. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks. That's what i thought , its better to delete the ones with 0 reads and for almost 30 indexes i see fixed writes as 18,235 and reads as 0. May be because of defrag and update stats being done on them, thats why a higher write ratio, Is there a way i can probe for the ratio? like on what parameters i can decided what ratio fits the situation here.

Comment: @Erik, thanks for the reply. How can i judge on indexes being an exact duplicate from the data i have gathered?

Comment: It isn't a data question it is a question of looking at the definition of the index. Keep in mind that order of columns matters with indexes so even if all of the same columns are in two indexes, if they are ordered differently then they aren't **exact** duplicates.

Comment: The ratio I'm talking about is simply `user_seeks + user_scans` to `user_updates`. But keep in mind these are *operation counts* not *row counts*. You could have a billion updates to single rows and 50,000 scans; the latter could be worse even though it's a much smaller number of operations. Again, these are all just ballpark guidelines and deleting an index requires *your* subjective judgment. Another piece of info you might want to have is the opinion of whoever actually requested or created the index you're about to delete - that'll be a more meaningful story than what the DMV tells you.